# How to obtain OpenAPI spec for Instagram APIs?

Tags: openapi, instagram-api

I am trying to create a service where I need to use Instagram APIs to fetch datapoints from the platform. It would greatly help if I had OpenAPI or Swagger spec for Instagram APIs. Please suggest where should I look for it? Also, if you have worked with Instagram APIs, how did you generate specs or how did you manage without one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no official OpenAPI definition for Instagram APIs.

Someone created an unofficial one here:
https://github.com/darklynx/swagger-api-collection/blob/master/api/yaml/instagram.yaml
but it was last updated in 2016 so it's likely very out-of-date.